# Why are shadow DOM events in a setTimeout re-targeted?

Tags: shadow-dom, custom-element

A custom element with a shadow DOM that listens for events on itself will (may?) have its events retargeted if those events are read from within a `setTimeout`:

```
<script>
    class Widget extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.attachShadowDom();
            this.registerListener();
        }
        attachShadowDom() {
            let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
            let templateClone = document.querySelector("#widget-template").content.cloneNode(true);
            shadow.appendChild(templateClone);
        }
        registerListener() {
            this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#my-input").addEventListener("input", (event) => {
                console.log(event.target);
                setTimeout(() => console.log(event.target), 0);
            });
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        customElements.define("my-widget", Widget);
    });
</script>

<html>
    <my-widget></my-widget>
</html>

<template id="widget-template">
    <input type="text" id="my-input">
</template>
```

Each character entered into the `input` element above logs 2 separate event targets to the console: the `input` element, and the `my-widget` element. I am wondering if this is by design?

Comment: I'm trying find a better way to phrase my question. It's weird because my intuition is that an arrow function would hold onto the values of `event.target`, but that is obviously untrue. Right now I'm telling myself: evaluating `event.target` from a closure after this event loop will re-evaluate it in document context, which implies it will undergo re-targeting. (So save a copy if you need the original target.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is by design.

As explained in [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events):

> The idea behind shadow tree is to encapsulate internal implementation details of a component [...]
>
> So, to keep the details encapsulated, the browser retargets the event.

And from [Google presentation of Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#events):

> When an `event` bubbles up from shadow DOM its target is adjusted to maintain the encapsulation that shadow DOM provides. That is, events are re-targeted to look like they've come from the component rather than internal elements within your shadow DOM.